# how to use "union" in ORACLE PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

i want use "union" but in this sql.
some problem was occured.

**PACKAGE BODY created with compilation error.
94/1  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:
( - + case mod new not null select with <식별자>
107/25  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LEFT" when expecting one of the following:
, ; for group having intersect minus order start union where
connect**

please help me..

```
PROCEDURE FILL_CALANDAR(V_CUR OUT R_CUR, in_uid VARCHAR2,in_std VARCHAR2)
    
    AS 
       PRD_RPT_Count     NUMBER;    
       PRD_SND_Count    NUMBER;     
       SCNR_SND_Count    NUMBER;     
       GREEKS_Count    NUMBER;    
       QST_Count    NUMBER;     
       ETC_Count    NUMBER;     
    BEGIN
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO PRD_RPT_Count FROM MZ_JOBSCHDMNG WHERE STD_DT = in_std AND JOB_CD = '1';  
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO PRD_SND_Count FROM MZ_JOBSCHDMNG WHERE STD_DT = in_std AND JOB_CD = '2';  
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO SCNR_SND_Count FROM MZ_JOBSCHDMNG WHERE STD_DT = in_std AND JOB_CD = '3'; 
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO GREEKS_Count FROM MZ_JOBSCHDMNG WHERE STD_DT = in_std AND JOB_CD = '4';   
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO QST_Count FROM MZ_JOBSCHDMNG WHERE STD_DT = in_std AND JOB_CD = '5';      
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ETC_Count FROM MZ_JOBSCHDMNG WHERE STD_DT = in_std AND JOB_CD = '6';     
    
    
    OPEN V_CUR FOR
    
    IF PRD_RPT_Count > 0 THEN 
          SELECT '0' AS CHK 
                            , A.JOB_CD
                            , M.CSCO_ID
                            , N.DEPT_ID
                            , A.HGITM_CNT
                            , A.WRK_YN
                            , A.WRKR
                            , A.EXAN_YN
                            , A.EXANR
                            , A.MEMO
                           FROM MZ_JOBSCHDMNG A
                            LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCOINFOM M ON (A.CSCO_ID = M.CSCO_ID )
                            LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCODEPTINFOM N ON (A.CSCO_ID = N.CSCO_ID AND A.DEPT_ID = N.DEPT_ID )
                            WHERE TO_CHAR(STD_DT,'YYYYMMDD') = in_std
                            AND A.JOB_CD = '1';
    ELSE
    
        SELECT  '0' AS CHK ,'1' AS JOB_CD,M.CSCO_ID,N.DEPT_ID,COUNT(A.PRD_RPT_DT) AS HGITM_CNT,'N' AS WRK_YN,'' AS WRKR,'N' AS EXAN_YN,'' AS EXANR,'' AS MEMO 
        from MZ_EVALCNTRBNDPRDINFOM A
            LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCOINFOM M ON (A.CSCO_ID = M.CSCO_ID )
            LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCODEPTINFOM N ON (A.CSCO_ID = N.CSCO_ID AND A.DEPT_ID = N.DEPT_ID )
        where PRD_RPT_DT = in_std
        GROUP BY M.CSCO_ID,N.DEPT_ID
        having COUNT(PRD_RPT_DT) > 0;
        
    END IF;
    
      UNION
    
    IF PRD_SND_Count > 0 THEN 
      SELECT '0' AS CHK 
                            , A.JOB_CD
                            , M.CSCO_ID
                            , N.DEPT_ID
                            , A.HGITM_CNT
                            , A.WRK_YN
                            , A.WRKR
                            , A.EXAN_YN
                            , A.EXANR
                            , A.MEMO
                           FROM MZ_JOBSCHDMNG A
                            LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCOINFOM M ON (A.CSCO_ID = M.CSCO_ID )
                            LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCODEPTINFOM N ON (A.CSCO_ID = N.CSCO_ID AND A.DEPT_ID = N.DEPT_ID )
                            WHERE TO_CHAR(STD_DT,'YYYYMMDD') = in_std
                            AND A.JOB_CD = '2';
    ELSE 
       SELECT '0' AS CHK , '2' AS JOB_CD,M.CSCO_ID,N.DEPT_ID,COUNT(A.PRD_SND_DT) AS HGITM_CNT,'N' AS WRK_YN,'' AS WRKR,'N' AS EXAN_YN,'' AS EXANR,'' AS MEMO 
            from MZ_EVALCNTRBNDPRDINFOM A
            LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCOINFOM M ON (A.CSCO_ID = M.CSCO_ID )
        LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCODEPTINFOM N ON (A.CSCO_ID = N.CSCO_ID AND A.DEPT_ID = N.DEPT_ID )
        where PRD_SND_DT = in_std
        GROUP BY M.CSCO_ID,N.DEPT_ID
        having COUNT(PRD_SND_DT) > 0;
    END IF;
    
        UNION
    
    IF SCNR_SND_Count > 0 THEN 
       SELECT '0' AS CHK 
                            , A.JOB_CD
                            , M.CSCO_ID
                            , N.DEPT_ID
                            , A.HGITM_CNT
                            , A.WRK_YN
                            , A.WRKR
                            , A.EXAN_YN
                            , A.EXANR
                            , A.MEMO
                           FROM MZ_JOBSCHDMNG A
                            LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCOINFOM M ON (A.CSCO_ID = M.CSCO_ID )
                            LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCODEPTINFOM N ON (A.CSCO_ID = N.CSCO_ID AND A.DEPT_ID = N.DEPT_ID )
                            WHERE TO_CHAR(STD_DT,'YYYYMMDD') = in_std
                            AND A.JOB_CD = '3';
    ELSE 
         SELECT  '0' AS CHK ,'3' AS JOB_CD,M.CSCO_ID,N.DEPT_ID,COUNT(A.SCNR_SND_DT) AS HGITM_CNT,'N' AS WRK_YN,'' AS WRKR,'N' AS EXAN_YN,'' AS EXANR,'' AS MEMO 
            from MZ_EVALCNTRBNDPRDINFOM A
                LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCOINFOM M ON (A.CSCO_ID = M.CSCO_ID )
                LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCODEPTINFOM N ON (A.CSCO_ID = N.CSCO_ID AND A.DEPT_ID = N.DEPT_ID )
        where SCNR_SND_DT = in_std
        GROUP BY M.CSCO_ID,N.DEPT_ID
        having COUNT(SCNR_SND_DT) > 0;
    END IF;
    
         UNION
    
    IF GREEKS_Count > 0 THEN 
      SELECT '0' AS CHK 
                            , A.JOB_CD
                            , M.CSCO_ID
                            , N.DEPT_ID
                            , A.HGITM_CNT
                            , A.WRK_YN
                            , A.WRKR
                            , A.EXAN_YN
                            , A.EXANR
                            , A.MEMO
                           FROM MZ_JOBSCHDMNG A
                            LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCOINFOM M ON (A.CSCO_ID = M.CSCO_ID )
                            LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCODEPTINFOM N ON (A.CSCO_ID = N.CSCO_ID AND A.DEPT_ID = N.DEPT_ID )
                            WHERE TO_CHAR(STD_DT,'YYYYMMDD') = in_std
                            AND A.JOB_CD = '4';
    ELSE 
        SELECT  '0' AS CHK ,'4' AS JOB_CD,M.CSCO_ID,N.DEPT_ID,COUNT(A.GREEKS_SND_DT) AS HGITM_CNT,'N' AS WRK_YN,'' AS WRKR,'N' AS EXAN_YN,'' AS EXANR,'' AS MEMO 
            from MZ_EVALCNTRBNDPRDINFOM A
            LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCOINFOM M ON (A.CSCO_ID = M.CSCO_ID )
            LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCODEPTINFOM N ON (A.CSCO_ID = N.CSCO_ID AND A.DEPT_ID = N.DEPT_ID )
        where GREEKS_SND_DT = in_std
        GROUP BY M.CSCO_ID,N.DEPT_ID
        having COUNT(GREEKS_SND_DT) > 0; 
    END IF;
    
         UNION
    
      SELECT '0' AS CHK 
                            , A.JOB_CD
                            , M.CSCO_ID
                            , N.DEPT_ID
                            , A.HGITM_CNT
                            , A.WRK_YN
                            , A.WRKR
                            , A.EXAN_YN
                            , A.EXANR
                            , A.MEMO
                           FROM MZ_JOBSCHDMNG A
                            LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCOINFOM M ON (A.CSCO_ID = M.CSCO_ID )
                            LEFT JOIN MZ_CSCODEPTINFOM N ON (A.CSCO_ID = N.CSCO_ID AND A.DEPT_ID = N.DEPT_ID )
                            WHERE TO_CHAR(STD_DT,'YYYYMMDD') = in_std
                            AND A.JOB_CD IN ('5','6');
    
    END FILL_CALANDAR;
```

Comment: `open cursor for ...` requires SQL statement as an argument, and SQL language have no `if` statement. SQL statement is not a free text, it has [predefined structure](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html). Either embed `where YOUR_CORRESPONDING_count > 0` for each part of the union or create required indexes and avoid doubled table scan by fingering tables directly in the SQL statement instead of separate statement for count

Comment: so how do i resolve my problem?...

Comment: What logic you are trying to implement here?

Answer (score 0):

Not like that; put `IF` conditions into `WHERE` clauses so that they *filter* data:

- `IF` will be "positive" condition, e.g. `where prd_rpt_count > 0`
- `ELSE` will be *negative* condition, e.g. `where NOT prd_rpt_count > 0`

Simplified:

```
open v_cur for
  -- the 1st IF from your code:
  select '0' ans chk, a.job_cd, ...
    from ...
    where prd_rpt_count > 0                  --> positive condition
  union
  select '0' as chk, '1' as job_cd, ...
    from ...
    where NOT prd_rpt_count > 0              --> negative condition
  --
  union
  --
  -- the 2nd IF from your code
  select '0' as chk, a.job_cd, ...
    from ...
    where prd_snd_count > 0                  --> positive condition
  union
  select '0' as chk, '2' as job_cd, ...
    from ...
    where NOT prd_snd_count > 0              --> negative condition
  --
  union 
  ...
  etc.
```